# Can you use PyCharm's breakpoint to change local variable?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

is there a way to use PyCharms advanced breakpoint abilities to change the local variable value?
I know I can do that manually when the code stops at the breakpoint, but I want to do it automatically without suspending the code run.

**Example:** I have a code, with `iDelay = 10` and in loop `time.sleep(iDelay)`. Can I use the breakpoint like below so I don't need to wait during debugging?

[image: this]

Comment: btw, you won the up vote privilege. Try it out, there's a badge for using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the sane way is to add some specific debug shortcuts to your source code, e.g. in case there's a special environment variable set or something.

In the meantime you can go absolutely crazy with breakpoint conditions (or even patch the debugger Python backend, see `pydevd.py` path in the debug output console). For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "Evaluate and Log" is only used to log runtime values. If you want to modify runtime values, that must be done manually.